# SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: php

```
include("class.phpmailer.php");
include("class.smtp.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 465; // set the port to use
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "******@gmail.com"; // your SMTP username or your gmail username
$mail->Password = "******"; // your SMTP password or your gmail password
$from = "***********@example.com"; // Reply to this email
$to="******@gmail.com"; // Recipients email ID
$name=" Name"; // Recipient's name
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = "Webmaster"; // Name to indicate where the email came from when the recepient received
$mail->AddAddress($to,$name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($from,"Webmaster");
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$mail->Subject = "Sending Email From Php Using Gmail";
$mail->Body = "This Email Send through phpmailer, This is the HTML BODY "; //HTML Body
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

am getting this error

> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Comment: Use `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;` to find why error shows.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using SSL. Add this line of code

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

Also change your

`$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";`

to

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

Also, make sure if you have enabled the extension **`php_openssl.dll`**

Comment: still get SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Comment: which webserver you are using ?

Comment: Is your php_openssl.dll enabled ? Have you restarted the wampserver after enabling the extension ? Try that and let know.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure your username and password are correct
then do these steps

**1** $mail -> SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

**2** $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

**3** `https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754`

**4** go to google acocunts then connected app and change to less secure apps on
follow all steps in number **3**